# Cannot create file that doesn't already exist

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ntfs

I'm trying to create a file by writing to it, and I'm being given the error that it does not exist (of course it doesn't --I'm trying to create it!)

I know about the problem where the *path* to the file doesn't exist (e.g. if I were to type `touch /path/to/folder/file_x` , and the *directory* `/path/to/folder/` didn't exist, then this would make sense.) That's **not** what's happening here.
I'm in the local directory where I want to create the file (no path issues).

```
touch file_a
touch file_b  # <-- these files are created, no problem
```

but for a particular filename that I had created earlier and already deleted, this breaks:

```
touch  file_x
touch: cannot touch 'file_x': No such file or directory
```

I also can't delete it:

```
rm file_x
rm: cannot remove 'file_x': No such file or directory
```

I can't delete what doesn't exist, but I also can't create it again. I don't understand how this is possible. This is on an NTFS drive, so perhaps there's a problem with Linux mounting a windows drive?

Comment: if NTFS you need to add the mount options it has. If the system is READ ONLY you can not touch a file and can not delete it.  file_a and file_b are made on the same dir as File_x at the aame moment?

Comment: Case sensitivity might be a play. Does `file_x` or `fiLe_x` or `FILE_X` or some other variation on case already exist?

Comment: @muru my apologies for writing the initial question with inconsistent case (which I can see created confusion; I've made everything consistent now). If I try to create `file_X` then that works fine, so case-sensitivity is as expected. It's just the very specific name `file_x` that seems to be "blocked" somehow --not quite deleted, but also not available.

Comment: What is the actual name of `file_x`? Perhaps windows does not allow certain file names, and NTFS follows the rules

Comment: The actual name is `sampleList_2023.08.29.json` (I thought abstraction would be simpler)

Comment: maybe the file is deleted but still open from another program ? Check `lsof`. Does it still persist after remount or reboot?